# Passing array to unmanaged code and returning back without copying

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, c++-cli, parameter-passing

I have a C++ library and I'm writing C# wrapper over it.
I'm stuck on passing array to unmanaged and reading it back in .NET.

What I want is a wrapper function that will get array of floats as a parameter (managed), process it in unmanaged function and return it as managed array.

Right now I'm doing this by creating C++ array, copying values from managed to unmanaged and then passing it as parameter to native function call. After that i must copy results back to send it back to managed code.

Here is my current approach:

```
array<float>^ Process(int samplesCount, array<float>^ audiodata){
    float* audioData[1];
    //copying to unmanaged
    audioData[0] = new float[samplesCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < samplesCount; ++i){
        audioData[0][i] = audiodata[i];
    }

    //process unmanaged
                    //int numSamples  //float *const *arrayOfChannels
    _filter->process(samplesCount,    audioData);

    //copying back from unmanaged
    array<float> ^result = gcnew array<float>(samplesCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < samplesCount; ++i){
        result[i] = audioData[0][i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

The catch is, that _filter->process() function takes float *const *arrayOfChannels as second parameter and that is most difficult for me.
So it will accept something like this:

```
// create a two channel audio buffer
int numSamples = 2000;
float* audioData[2];
audioData[0] = new float[numSamples];
audioData[1] = new float[numSamples];
// and somewhere after:
_filter->process (numSamples, audioData);
```

Is there a possibility to pass `float *const *arrayOfChannels` parameter from managed world without copying arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this without copying. Use [pin_ptr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh.aspx) to get a plain `float*` that's pointing at your managed data, and then put that pointer into whatever structure you need.

Note that by passing the managed arrays to unmanaged code, you'll end up changing the parameter passing for your `Process` method: The unmanaged code is modifying the array that was passed to it, and since you're passing the managed array to the unmanaged code, that's what you'll end up with in your managed code. `Process` would change to returning `void`, and modifying the contents of the input arrays.

Also note if a garbage collection happens while the array is pinned, the garbage collector has to do extra work, because it's no longer allowed to move memory around. Therefore, you want to keep the arrays pinned for as short a time as possible, just long enough to call the unmanaged method.

```
void Process(array<float>^ channel1, array<float>^ channel2)
{
    pin_ptr<float> pinned1 = &channel1[0];
    float* asPointer1 = pinned1;

    pin_ptr<float> pinned2 = &channel2[0];
    float* asPointer2 = pinned2;

    float* audioData[2];
    audioData[0] = asPointer1;
    audioData[1] = asPointer2;

    _filter->process(channel1->Length, audioData);
}
```

Comment: There is no extra work behind pin_ptr<>, it simply turns a bit on in the GC context table that says that, if a collection happens, that the object should not be moved.

Comment: That's a good point, it only impacts the GC if a collection happens while the object is pinned. Corrected.